# Image upload problems in laravel package Intervention/Image

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload images using the intervention/Image package in laravel. It works fine for smaller size images, but when I try to upload larger images, it throws following exception.

> Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ InvalidImageTypeException Wrong
>   image type () only use JPG, PNG or GIF images.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$image=Input::file('photo');
$filename=date('Ymdhis')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save('public/img/'.$filename)
```

Comment: I used it and didn't face any problems like this, maybe you should post some related code/settings.

Comment: Agreed, if there is a config file for this package or any sort of code you can show us, that would help.

Comment: I've posted the code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the same issue I am having.  The image you are uploading is likely one taken on a mobile phone, if you `dd(Input::file('photo'));` you'll notice that the MIME type is not `image/jpg` but `application/octet-stream` instead.  Since it's not an "image" mime type, Intervention throws up.  I have yet you find a solution to the problem but when I do I'll remember to update this comment.

Comment: the same problem here